# How to add a scrollbar for Frame in tkinter python and scroll it with mousewheel?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, frame, mousewheel

I need to create a scrollbar for Frame with mousewheel scorlling in tkinter library.

I tried to set yview for Frame
`scrollbar = Scrollbar(master, command=frame.yview)`
but frame doesn't have yview method.

I tried to set frame.yscrollcommand for scrollbar too, but it doesn't work

Please, help me.

Comment: A frame is not scrollable.  You can put a frame inside a canvas and scroll the canvas to see different part of the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Tkinter doesn't have a scrollable frame.

What you can do instead:
Create a Canvas and make it scrollable. Like acw1668 said.
I created a class for that that runs only on **Linux**

```
import tkinter as tk

class Scroll_Frame(tk.Frame):
    """ frame_options is the scrollable frame"""
    def __init__(self, master=None, bg="grey22", height=300, width=300, *args, **kwargs):
        self.master = master
        self.height_ = height
        self.width_ = width
        self.background = bg
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.master)
        self.grid()
        self.rowconfigure((0), weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure((0), weight=1)
        
        self.flag_focus_canvas = False
        
        self.canvas_scroll = tk.Canvas(self, bg=self.background, height=self.height_, width=self.width_, *args, **kwargs)
        self.canvas_scroll.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="wesn")#, padx=20, pady=20)
        
        self.scrollbar_v = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", 
                                         command=self.canvas_scroll.yview)
        self.scrollbar_v.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="ns")
        self.canvas_scroll.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_v.set) 
               
        self.scrollbar_h = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", 
                                         command=self.canvas_scroll.xview)
        self.scrollbar_h.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="we")
        self.canvas_scroll.configure(xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_h.set) 
        
        self.frame_options = tk.Frame(self.canvas_scroll, bg=self.background, *args, **kwargs)

        self.frame_options.bind("<Configure>", 
                                lambda e: self.canvas_scroll.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas_scroll.bbox("all")))

        self.canvas_scroll.create_window(0,0, window=self.frame_options, anchor="nw", tags="scrollable")
        
        self.canvas_scroll.bind_all("<Button-4>", lambda e: self._on_mousewheel(e))
        self.canvas_scroll.bind_all("<Button-5>", lambda e: self._on_mousewheel(e))
        self.canvas_scroll.bind("<Enter>", lambda e: self.set_focus_scroll(e))
        self.canvas_scroll.bind("<Leave>", lambda e: self.unset_focus_scroll(e))
    
    def set_focus_scroll(self, event):
        self.flag_focus_canvas = True

    def unset_focus_scroll(self, event):
        self.flag_focus_canvas = False
        
    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        if event.num == 4:
            if self.flag_focus_canvas:
                self.canvas_scroll.yview_scroll(int(-1), "units")
        if event.num == 5:
            if self.flag_focus_canvas:
                self.canvas_scroll.yview_scroll(int(1), "units")
                
    def get_scroll_frame(self):
        """returns the real scroll frame,
        this is the place you put all your widgets in"""
        return self.frame_options
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Scroll_Frame(root)  
    scroll_frame = app.get_scroll_frame()  
    for i in range(20):
        tk.Button(scroll_frame, text=f"Button {i}").grid(sticky="we")
    root.mainloop()
```

Now you can get the frame **scroll_frame = app.get_scroll_frame()** and put in whatever you want, for demonstration purposes I put buttons.

Windows creates different events, so you need to change bindings:

```
#Windows bind mousewheel
                
def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
    if self.flag_focus_canvas:
        self.canvas_scroll.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")
        
self.canvas_scroll.bind("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)
```

*Enjoy*

Comment: For Linux check `if event.state&1 != 0`. It will tell you if the user is using a touchpad to scroll horizontally. Also why do you have have `self.frame_options.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="wesn")`? I don't think it's needed.

Comment: @TheLizzard You are right it is an artifact from my project, I will remove it. thanks

Comment: you can bind self._on_mousewheel() function with event <MouseWheel> too
and you need to change scrolling inself._on_mousewheel like this
`self.canvas_scroll.yview_scroll(-event.delta / SPEED_DIVISON, "units")`
and it will work on windows too